# Loading text into a list box

Tags: vb.net

The main goal that I need to achieve is to make the details entered by the user (such as minutes used and total cost etc.) to be shown to the user in one list once all boxes have been filled out. They would then be able to save the text within that box/listbox to a txt file on the PC.

That is pretty much all I need to do. I cant seem to get that to happen and have no idea of how I can do that. This is the code that I have so far which works how it should.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    End Sub

    Private Sub btn1TotalCost_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn1TotalCost.Click

        'Declaring the variables.
        Dim MinutesAllowed As Integer
        Dim MinutesUsed As Integer
        Dim TextsAllowed As Integer
        Dim TextsUsed As Integer
        Dim DataAllowed As Integer
        Dim DataUsed As Integer
        Dim MinutesTotalCost As Double
        Dim TextsTotalCost As Double
        Dim DataTotalCost As Double
        Dim MonthlyCost As Double
        Dim TotalCost As Double

        MinutesAllowed = Val(txtBoxMinutesAllowed.Text)
        MinutesUsed = Val(txtBoxMinutesUsed.Text)
        TextsAllowed = Val(txtBoxTextsAllowed.Text)
        TextsUsed = Val(txtBoxTextsUsed.Text)
        DataAllowed = Val(txtBoxDataAllowed.Text)
        DataUsed = Val(txtBoxDataUsed.Text)
        MinutesTotalCost = Val(txtBoxTotalCost.Text)
        TextsTotalCost = Val(txtBoxTotalCost.Text)
        DataTotalCost = Val(txtBoxTotalCost.Text)
        TotalCost = Val(txtBoxTotalCost.Text)

        'Calculation For Minutes
        MinutesAllowed = Val(txtBoxMinutesAllowed.Text)
        MinutesUsed = Val(txtBoxMinutesUsed.Text)
        MonthlyCost = Val(txtBoxMonthlyCost.Text)
        'If the minutes allowed is greater than or equal to the minutes used, no extra charge is added.
        If MinutesAllowed >= MinutesUsed Then
            MinutesTotalCost = 0
        Else 'If the minutes used is greater than the minutes allowed, each minute is multiplied by 00.30p.
            MinutesTotalCost = (MinutesUsed - MinutesAllowed) * 0.3
        End If
        txtBoxTotalCost.Text = CType(MinutesTotalCost + MonthlyCost, String)



        'Calculation For Texts
        TextsAllowed = Val(txtBoxTextsAllowed.Text)
        TextsUsed = Val(txtBoxTextsUsed.Text)
        MonthlyCost = Val(txtBoxMonthlyCost.Text)
        'If the texts allowed is greater than or equal to the texts used, no extra charge is added.
        If TextsAllowed >= TextsUsed Then
            TextsTotalCost = 0
        Else 'If the texts used is greater than the texts allowed, each text is multiplied by 00.15p.
            TextsTotalCost = (TextsUsed - TextsAllowed) * 0.15
        End If
        txtBoxTotalCost.Text = CType(TextsTotalCost + MonthlyCost, String)



        'Calculation For Data
        DataAllowed = Val(txtBoxDataAllowed.Text)
        DataUsed = Val(txtBoxDataUsed.Text)
        MonthlyCost = Val(txtBoxMonthlyCost.Text)
        'If the data allowed is greater than or equal to the data used, no extra charge is added.
        If DataAllowed >= DataUsed Then
            DataTotalCost = 0
        Else 'If the data used is greater than the data allowed, 10.00 is added to the total cost.
            DataTotalCost = 10
        End If
        txtBoxTotalCost.Text = CType(DataTotalCost + MonthlyCost + TextsTotalCost + MinutesTotalCost, Double)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: PhoneNumber probably shouldn't be a Decimal.  Why are you trying to set all your number variables = ""?

Comment: @LarsTech I know but I've tried Integer, Double and Decimal but to no avail

Comment: You assigning string to a decimal. What did u try to achieve? Either define PhoneNumber as string or assign it a numeric value, e.g 0

Comment: @YuriyGalanter I need the number to load up into the list box so that it can be saved onto a file within the computer. Thats it really.

Comment: Are you even reading the code? `Dim TotalCost as Double;` and `TotalCost = ""` don't  make sense, do they? How do you assign an **empty string** to a variable of type **Double** and not expect to get an exception? Now repeat that question for all of the `Integer` variables that you're also trying to initialize to `""`.

Comment: 1) You don't need to load into a listbox so you can save into a file. A listbox is a UI control. It is used for displaying content to the user. 2) A phone  number is a string. It is not an Integer, Double, or anything else. A phone number contains content other than numeric digits, such as spaces, dashes, parentheses, etc.

Comment: @KenWhite So how would I get the number to be assigned into the list box from the text box? Thats all I need to achieve.

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks for that, ill try that now and fix it up a lil'

Comment: The error  is not related to putting the text box into the listbox. It's coming before that (as your image clearly indicates), at the line `PhoneNumber = ""`, which clearly won't work since you've declared PhoneNumber as a Double. If you don't understand the difference between a Double, an Integer, and a String, you should find a tutorial somewhere.

Comment: Do what Plutonix said. Put this line at the very top of your code file: `Option Strict On`

Comment: The problem was solved therefore I updated the question saying that I had solved it, providing the correct code for other users who may face the same thing.

Comment: You should add the correct code as an answer and mark it as accepted rather than change your question. Just a heads up for  next time. Cheers.

Comment: @FutureProgrammer David WIlson is correct - please post your solution as an answer if you solved it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

OK. This code to be brutally honest isn't good. These lines

```
Dim FullName As String
Dim PhoneNumber As Decimal
Dim AccNumber As Decimal
Dim MinutesAllowed As Integer
Dim TextsAllowed As Integer
Dim DataAllowed As Integer
Dim MinutesUsed As Integer
Dim TextsUsed As Integer
Dim DataUsed As Integer
Dim MonthlyCost As Double
Dim TotalCost As Double
```

are declaring variables of specific types - strings,decimals and integers and so on. That means they can only accept values that are the same type. Having **Option Strict On** in your code will help you correct these errors as it will show errors you have with your code.  These lines should be:

```
FullName = ""
PhoneNumber = 0D
AccNumber = 0D
MinutesAllowed = 0
TextsAllowed = 0
DataAllowed = 0
MinutesUsed = 0
TextsUsed = 0
DataUsed = 0
MonthlyCost = 0R
TotalCost = 0R
```

The reason you're having problems is that you can't assign an empty string to an integer or any other number. With **Option Strict** on, these errors will show up. Incidendtally you would be better declaring phoneNumber as a string to allow dashes and brackets etc. Also if TotalCost is a double then MonthlyCost should also be double

The letters after the numbers indicate the type of the number being asssigned. **D** means that it's a decimal 0 and **R** means that it's a double 0. However in your code as it stands, when variables are declared, they are already assigned default values anyway, so you don't really need the lines assigning values

Moving on ..

```
listBox.Items.Add("Full Name: " + txtBoxFullName.Text)
listBox.Items.Add("Phone Number: " + txtBoxPhoneNumber.Text)
```

and so on

The lines above are completely unrelated the the variable declarations above. Is this intentional? For example txtBoxFullName.Text isn't the same variable as FullName at all and unless you have other code, I dont see the need for the above variables. I'm guessing that the code you've posted is incomplete. When you're posting a question, you really need to post all the relevant code. Have a look here .. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Listen to Plutonix - He is WISE.